# VS 2015 Solution Explorer não identifica arquivo alterado (Controle de versão TFVC)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, versionamento, team-foundation-server

Estou aprendendo sobre versionamento com `TFVC` e `Git`.

Projetos versionados com `Git` os arquivos modificados são marcados com um símbolo indicando que ouve alteração (`commit` pendente)

Já projetos gerenciados com `TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control)` o mesmo não acontece.

Alguém já passou por isso? Estou utilizando `VS2015 PRO update 2`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz alguma cagada quando criei este projeto, fiz um teste criando um novo e funciona normalmente. Uma das diferenças que notei foi a ausência do arquivo `.vssscc` no projeto problemático. Não sei onde esse arquivo foi parar. :/

Comment: Tudo certo.  :) @LuizVieira

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação mais detalhada do problema  (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e8c02b7-827b-4ec9-b81b-18101e04a000/vs-2015-tfvc-solution-explorer-pending-changes-icons-not-displayed?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: Bom, com base no link que vc mandou, parece ser um problema meio recorrente sim. Retirei meu voto pra fechar. Desculpe a confusão. :)

Comment: Encontrei a solução, vou postar como resposta em breve! \0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recriar os arquivos responsáveis pelo versionamento (`VS-2015`):

`File` > `Source Control` > `Advanced` > `Change Source Control`

Será mostrada a tela abaixo:

[image: Change source control]

Selecione a `Solution/Project` e clique em `Unbind`

**Funcionando :)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234443/adding-a-new-project-to-an-existing-solution-in-tfs)